# Civilization 5 unending turn?

Tags: civilization-5

So I just got a city out of an ideological revolt, its been annexed and yatta yatta. For whatever reason, I traded the city back to its original owner before telling it to produce something. Only now I can't end the turn because the city still needs me to tell it what to build, which I can't because it's not mine anymore. I've tried the shift+enter trick to no success. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: wasn't it strg + space to end a turn?

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to [this](http://steamcommunity.com/app/8930/discussions/0/666826703917411428/) page it's a known bug.

Some users recommended to perform a rightclick.
(I really don't know, how this may unstuck te game :D )
If this doesn't work you should have got the autosaves.
Which means you lose the last few Minutes.

Comment: Try right-clicking on the `choose production` button. If that doesn't work, the previous autosave may be your only hope. I highly recommend setting the frequency to every turn in the settings. Apparently, Civ5 is still not fully baked.